# Boostrap vertical align buttons but not content for responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 columns using boostrap each with some text content that are not even in height, the issue is I would like the buttons to align horizontally with each other at the bottom of each column.

It's easy to create another boostrap .row to make them align however this is not responsive, once the screen width shrinks the 3 columns will move into a vertical list and all the buttons will be after the 3 columns.

I have some example code here:

http://www.bootply.com/rA0yeogpQc#

So because of responsive the buttons have to be within the content container.

I have tried a few different things but seems like my solutions don't work with boostrap or have a responsive problem, would like to find a solution that works for all!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here in your example col-md-4 class is been used that means if you will shrink your screen more than medium screen size i.e. iPad or Tablet it will starts responsiveness.

To make sure it will not start responsive behavior you should use **col-xs-4** instead of **col-md-4**, it will not start responsiveness till extra small screen size ie. mobile phone screen

I have also corrected your code

http://www.bootply.com/Cww3x84W62

Hope this will works well for you.

Comment: Thank you but that's not really answering the question. How to get the buttons to align horizontally with each other?

Comment: ohh..you have to uncomment that commented code and edit that **col-md-4** to **col-xs-4** just like this please refer the **link** [http://www.bootply.com/QBB9Bgkl6f](http://www.bootply.com/QBB9Bgkl6f)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Can't say it's fully solved but it does work. Look at the HTML comment to see the caveats.

In a nutshell:

1. I have added a new class to the column (col-height-md). This class gives a fixed height to all the columns.
2. Had to insert a further `<div>` inside to be able to reset the position to relative

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/andrejmarinic/346txu9n/